# how to click on the page in facebook using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[image: Here is the Page that i want to go inside of it]when i compile my code it log in but the line that should click on the page does not work.
thats my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from Config import keys
import time


def order(k):
   driver = webdriver.Chrome('driver\chromedriver.exe')
   driver.get(k['product_url'])
   username ="gmail"
   pw ="password"
   #Enter The Pw & email fb
   driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]').send_keys(username)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]').send_keys(pw)
   #Click on cnx button
   driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_b"]').click()
   #go to the page
     # here is the problem
   driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/span/div/a').click()

   driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/a/span').click()
   driver.page_source()


if __name__=='__main__':
    order(keys)
```

Comment: Because your facebook homepage is constantly changing, I would avoid using a direct xpath like that. It may not be consistent. Can you verify if that xpath remains correct?

Comment: i just checked sir.
the xpath stay the same no change happened

Comment: What is mount_0_0?

Comment: no this xpath is wrong i changed it to see if it gonna work like that but look now in the code....

Comment: when i copy the xpath of the page in the image it looks like that
//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/span/div/a
and when i copy it the second time(second run) it looks like the first xpth
//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/span/div/a

Comment: Its profile specific better you explain functionality what are you doing once you logged in to fb

Comment: @DipakBachhav can i make it work without xpath

Comment: Actually I cant see that flag on my account so trying to understand what is that and if its common across all accounts and thats the reason I am asking you whaat are you trying to do. hopefully you have changed setting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211561/discussion-between-dipak-bachhav-and-zakaria-redouane).

Answer (score 1):

Could be due to synchronization issue try to induce  WebDriverWait :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='mount_0_0']/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/span/div/a"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='mount_0_0'']/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/a/span"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: @Zakaria Redouane: Not able to check locally but you can try above if its a synchronization issue

Comment: Now it works good 
im appreciate that a lot sir @Dipak Bqchhav

Comment: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer if your issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

After checking on the Facebook website, `'//*[@id="mount_0_0"]'` is the xpath of the main container. For the button you are trying to click, the xpath I have found is  :

```
//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/span/div/a
```

Maybe you could try with this one ?